# How do I solve for continuous compounding interest in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, math

I am working on a project where we have three variables and need to create a function that solves for continuous compound interest:

The three variables are:

1. Principle
2. Annual Interest Rate
3. Number of years

My current function is:

```
function compoundInterest(balance, interest, years) {
  balance *= Math.pow(Math.E, (1 + interest) * years);
  return balance;
}
```

I need to be following this formula from Wikipedia:

P(t)=P{0}e^{rt}

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 0):

Try this function:

```js
function compoundInterest(principal, annual_rate, n_times, t_years) {
    return principal*(Math.pow(1 + annual_rate/n_times, n_times*t_years) - 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any "1+" in your formula so there shouldn't be in your Javascript code either. From Wikipedia.

- P is the original principal sum
- r is the nominal annual interest rate
- t is the overall length of time the interest is applied (expressed using the same time units as r, usually years)

So if you want the Continuous compounding interest function P(t)=P{0}e^{rt}, you want the Javascript:

```
balance *= Math.pow(Math.E, interest * years);
```

.

Comment: Thank you so much! I just tried this and it worked perfectly.